# ¿Cómo recorro una cadena y obtengo la longitud de cada elemento en python?

Tags: python, string, bucles

Soy novato en python y tengo que hacer un ejercicio en el cual he estado tratando de resolverlo por mi cuenta durante dos días y no lo he logrado.

El enunciado dice:

"Escribir un programa que lea una colección de cadenas de caracteres de
longitud arbitraria. Por cada cadena leída, su programa hará lo siguiente:
**a.** Imprimir la longitud de la cadena.
**b.** Contar el número de ocurrencias de palabras de cuatro letras.
**c.** Sustituir cada palabra de cuatro letras por una cadena de cuatro
asteriscos e imprimir la nueva cadena."

Este es el código que he logrado escribir:

```
cadenaPalabras = 'Llevo dos dias tratando de hacer este ejercicio '
cadenaPalabras += 'pero no he logrado hacerlo funcionar, necesito ayuda'

listaPalabras = cadenaPalabras.split()
print("La cadena de palabras es: ")
print(listaPalabras)
print("La longitud de la frase es: ")
print (len(listaPalabras))

longitudes = []
for i in range(0, (len(listaPalabras[1]))):
    longitudes.append(len(listaPalabras[1][i]))

print(longitudes)
```

El asunto se me ha complicado ya que no logro construir un ciclo que recorra cada elemento de la cadena para luego reemplazar los elementos según el enunciado.

Se agradece de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Comment: debes hacer `for i in listaPalabras: longitudes.append(len(i))` no es necesario indicar la posicion o un rango, cada elemento se extrae y se asigna a `i`

Comment: No pero al momento de reemplazar la cadena si se nesecita el indice. @Bryro o eso creo.

Comment: Se agradece mucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución.

*Escribir un programa que lea una colección de cadenas de caracteres de longitud arbitraria*

Primero creamos una lista (*colección*) de cadenas:

```
cadenaPalabras = ['Llevo dos dias tratando de hacer este ejercicio ',
                  'pero no he logrado hacerlo funcionar, necesito ayuda',
                  'la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta']
```

La lista `cadenaPalabras` tiene tres cadenas. Para recorrerlas usamos el patron `for elemento in lista:`, que va tomando cada elemento de la lista.

```
for cadena in cadenaPalabras:
    procesar_cadena(cadena)
```

Ahora nos queda el problema de procesar **una** cadena en la función cuya declaración comienza asi:

```
def procesar_cadena(cadena):
```

Lo primero es imprimir la cadena recibida y su longitud:

```
print("Cadena: ", cadena)
print("Longitud: ", len(cadena))
```

A continuación dividimos la cadena en sus partes usando `split()`

```
palabras = cadena.split()
```

Si la cadena es

```
"Llevo dos dias tratando de hacer este ejercicio "
```

la función `split()` entrega la lista de palabras:

```
['Llevo', 'dos', 'dias', 'tratando', 'de', 'hacer', 'este', 'ejercicio']
```

Vamos a recorrer esta lista de palabras copiandolas a una nueva lista y aprovechando de hacer el reemplazo de las palabras de cuatro letras:

```
numero = 0  # El número de palabras de 4 letras en la cadena
nueva_cadena = [] # Las palabras transformadas.
for palabra in palabras:
    if len(palabra) == 4:
        numero += 1
        nueva_cadena.append("****")
    else:
        nueva_cadena.append(palabra)
print("Palabras de 4 letras: ", numero)
```

Nos contara las palabras

```
Palabras de 4 letras:  2
```

y dejara la siguiente lista `nueva_cadena`:

```
['Llevo', 'dos', '****', 'tratando', 'de', 'hacer', '****', 'ejercicio']
```

Para formar la nueva cadena, usamos `join()`

```
print("Nueva cadena: ", ' '.join(nueva_cadena))
```

que produce:

```
"Llevo dos **** tratando de hacer **** ejercicio"
```

El código completo:

```
def procesar_cadena(cadena):
    print("Cadena: ", cadena)
    print("Longitud: ", len(cadena))
    palabras = cadena.split()
    numero = 0
    nueva_cadena = []
    for palabra in palabras:
        if len(palabra) == 4:
            numero += 1
            nueva_cadena.append("****")
        else:
            nueva_cadena.append(palabra)
    print("Palabras de 4 letras: ", numero)
    print("Nueva cadena: ", ' '.join(nueva_cadena))
    print()

cadenaPalabras = ['Llevo dos dias tratando de hacer este ejercicio ',
                  'pero no he logrado hacerlo funcionar, necesito ayuda',
                  'la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta']
for cadena in cadenaPalabras:
    procesar_cadena(cadena)
```

produce:

```
Cadena:  Llevo dos dias tratando de hacer este ejercicio 
Longitud:  48
Palabras de 4 letras:  2
Nueva cadena:  Llevo dos **** tratando de hacer **** ejercicio

Cadena:  pero no he logrado hacerlo funcionar, necesito ayuda
Longitud:  52
Palabras de 4 letras:  1
Nueva cadena:  **** no he logrado hacerlo funcionar, necesito ayuda

Cadena:  la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta
Longitud:  38
Palabras de 4 letras:  1
Nueva cadena:  la **** jacinta se ha puesto una cinta
```

Comment: Se agradece mucho el tiempo, la explicación tan dellada y la amabilidad.

Comment: @alonsogamboa ¿Te funcionó esta respuesta?. Porque si es asi te recomiendo que la coloques como la mejor. Porque asi les dices a los futuros lectores que esta es la respuesta.

Comment: Le di a "aceptar esta respuesta". ¿ Eso es lo que mencionaste?